# How to eval script tag while setting Node.innerHTML = SomeTagString

Tags: javascript

while the server return a string contains some node tags like:

```
<div>Information</div>
<script>alert("some Code")</script>
```

And I have to paste it in a container(like a div tag)
My question is :how to get the script tag's code run?
I've did some tests,I found that while creating a script tag and put some codes in it,and
`Container.appendChild(scriptTag)`would work,but in my case,is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, `Node.innerHTML` would not trigger the execution of script. `Node.appendChild` is OK. If you do not prefer this manner, you can `eval` your script code manually.

```
eval(scriptElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: ,The question is ,how to find out the scriptElement in a bunch of Tag String

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `defer` attribute to the script.

```
<script defer>alert("some code");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery .html method, it's works ok with jquery1.10+

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When answering a question, you should describe how the method that you're suggesting applies to the problem in the question.